# running python script again based on user answer using decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

Im trying to run the script again, based on user input(y/n). In my main file Im calling couple of functions from another file, with the decorator Ive seen its usage in older post here, but cant find why Im getting an error: "
game()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable "

```
    def restartable(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            answer = 'y'
            while answer == 'y':
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                while True:
                    answer = input("Play Again? y/n")
                    if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                        break
                    else:
                        print("invalid answer")
            return wrapper()



@restartable
def game():
  items = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

  balance = support.get_deposit()

  deposit, balance = support.accept_bet(balance)

  spin_machine = support.spin_machine(items)

  support.matrix_out(spin_machine)

  coef = support.check_col(spin_machine)

  support.calculate_money(balance, deposit, coef)



game()
```

I know this can be done in a While loop and many different ways, I just wanted it done with decorator :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `return wrapper` line is miss indented, and you should return the function without calling it.

```py
def restartable(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        answer = 'y'
        while answer == 'y':
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            while True:
                answer = input("Play Again? y/n")
                if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                    break
                else:
                    print("invalid answer")
    return wrapper
```

should work.